# Julia strange answer from indexing an array

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I'm attempting to index an array based on conditions in the array itself and corresponding locations in other arrays. I've produced a MWE but this will be hopefully used in a much larger example, within a loop to automate across scenarios, dare I say... using parallelisation?

MWE:

```
# create 3d array
a, b, c = [8;8;6;5;5;6], [8;8;7;6;6;6], [8;2;7;7;6;6]
d = transpose(cat(a,b,c, dims = 2))
e, f, g = [3;2;5;1;4;1], [4;3;1;1;1;2], [5;1;2;1;2;3]
h = transpose(cat(e,f,g, dims = 2))
wrkarr = cat(d,h,dims = 3)

# create temp array for indexes
temp = wrkarr[size(wrkarr,1), :, 1]

# calculate indexes
temp[(wrkarr[size(wrkarr,1),:,1] .== 8) .& (wrkarr[size(wrkarr,1),:,2]) .>= 4] .= 22
```

In my case it doesn't change anything in the temp array, when I would expect the first element to be changed from `8` to `22`. Both of the individual conditional tests produce a vector `[1,0,0,0,0,0]` so why won't the `.&` test produce the same?  Thx. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, and as an aside, please note that you can use `arr[end,i]` to refer to the element `arr` with the last index in the 1st axis, and index `i` in the second axis.

Using this notation, your condition can be rewritten as:

```
julia> (wrkarr[end,:,1] .== 8) .& (wrkarr[end,:,2]) .>=4
6-element BitArray{1}:
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

It might be a bit easier to see here that there is a parenthesis issue. I think you actually wanted to write:

```
julia> (wrkarr[end,:,1] .== 8) .& (wrkarr[end,:,2] .>=4)
6-element BitArray{1}:
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

Making this change does what (I think) you want. (Also note that I added `@view`s below in order to avoid allocations and speed things up a little)

```
julia> idx = (@view(wrkarr[end,:,1]) .== 8) .& (@view(wrkarr[end,:,2]) .>=4);
julia> temp[idx] .= 22
1-element view(::Array{Int64,1}, [1]) with eltype Int64:
 22

julia> temp
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 22
  2
  7
  7
  6
  6
```

---

EDIT: as mentioned in comments, other solutions could be considered:

1. using `findall` to generate a vector of indices matching the condition
2. using a simple `for` loop

Here is a benchmark of all three solutions, in order to see how they compare in terms of readability and performance.

TLDR: the for loop seems to be much more efficient in this case, and allocates less.

```
# create 3d array
d = [8  8  6  5  5  6;
     8  8  7  6  6  6;
     8  2  7  7  6  6]

h = [3  2  5  1  4  1;
     4  3  1  1  1  2;
     5  1  2  1  2  3]

wrkarr = cat(d,h,dims = 3)

using BenchmarkTools
```

**Option 1** logical indexing

```
julia> function version1!(temp, wrkarr)
           idx = (@view(wrkarr[end,:,1]) .== 8) .& (@view(wrkarr[end,:,2]) .>= 4)
           temp[idx] .= 22
       end

version1! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp = wrkarr[end, :, 1]; @btime version1!($temp, $wrkarr); temp
  182.646 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 22
  2
  7
  7
  6
  6
```

**Option 2** vector of indices

```
julia> function version2!(temp, wrkarr)
           idx = findall(i -> (wrkarr[end,i,1] == 8) & (wrkarr[end,i,2] >=4), axes(wrkarr,2))
           temp[idx] .= 22
       end
version2! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp = wrkarr[end, :, 1]; @btime version2!($temp, $wrkarr); temp
  134.395 ns (3 allocations: 208 bytes)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 22
  2
  7
  7
  6
  6
```

**Option 3** `for` loop

```
julia> function version3!(temp, wrkarr)
           @inbounds for i in axes(wrkarr, 2)
               if wrkarr[end, i, 1] == 8 && wrkarr[end, i, 2] >= 4
                   temp[i] = 22
               end
           end
       end

version3! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp = wrkarr[end, :, 1]; @btime version3!($temp, $wrkarr); temp
  21.820 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 22
  2
  7
  7
  6
  6
```

Comment: You could also consider `idx = findall(i -> (wrkarr[end,i,1] == 8) & (wrkarr[end,i,2] >=4), axes(wrkarr,2))`, a vector of integers instead of a BitVector mask.

Comment: @mcabbott, Thanks for that.  Close but not quite, for some reason this code just produces an empty array called idx for me.  Is it missing some "." 's anwhere like in front of the =, &, and >    ?  Rather than bothering to create an array of indexes, shouldn't I be able to just do the substitution right into the original array?

Comment: This gives `[1]` for me, with your input. Perhaps even better is `idx = findall(i -> wrkarr[end,i,1] == 8 && wrkarr[end,i,2] >=4, axes(wrkarr,2))` which avoids the precedence issue. But no dots needed, the things inside the function here are scalars. 

You could place any of these within `temp[idx] .= 22`'s brackets, which saves you from naming the array of indices, but doesn't avoid its creation. The broadcasted versions create both a BitArray to index, and slices `wrkarr[end,:,1]::Vector`; the latter could be avoided with `@views`.

Comment: Thanks @mcabbott, I edited my answer to present your solution, along with a comparison to a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the clever stuff given to me above I pushed it a bit further and this solution appears to work and dispenses with the need for an index array, simply does the substitution right back into the original array.  Is there anything wrong with that?  Looking at @François Févotte's answer the loop function is the fastest, and this could be very important when scaled up to proper size.  Now for my next challenge I want to use the same function to loop through sets of numbers to replace the 8, 4, 22, for example for the same wrkarr:

```
== 8 &>= 4  ->  22
== 7 &>= 2  ->  8
== 6 &>= 3  ->  7
```

Any takers or suggestions?  When I get that to work I want to see if it can be parallelized across these individual sets of numbers, i.e. each substitution can be done independently, not dependent on any other.  Thx a bunch!

```
function version4(wrkarr)
    @inbounds for i in axes(wrkarr, 2)
        if wrkarr[end, i, 1] == 8 && wrkarr[end, i, 2] >= 4
            wrkarr[end,i, 1] = 22
        end
    end
end

wrkarr[end, :, 1]; @btime version4($wrkarr); wrkarr
  2.237 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3×6×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  8  8  6  5  5  6
  8  8  7  6  6  6
 22  2  7  7  6  6

[:, :, 2] =
 3  2  5  1  4  1
 4  3  1  1  1  2
 5  1  2  1  2  3
```